# Want to copy cell value not formula in n times copy function

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub CopyHeaders()
Dim copyTimes As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim n As Integer

   copyTimes = Range("B3")
If copyTimes > 0 Then
    For i = 1 To copyTimes
    Range("C3").Copy Cells((i * 1) + 1, "F")
    Next i
End If   
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seemed to work for me.

```
Option Explicit

Sub CopyHeaders()
    Dim copyTimes As Long
    copyTimes = Range("B3")

    If copyTimes > 0 Then
        Range("F2").Resize(copyTimes).Value = Range("C3").Value
    End If
End Sub
```

You could also use `Range.Copy` and `Range.PasteSpecial`, if you want more control over the paste type (e.g. just values, just values and number formatting, and so forth).